# Building ffmpeg-kit for android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, aar, ffmpegkit

I want to create an AAR dependency for my Android project, where I only convert video to audio files and use ffprobe to extract media information. https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit

I am using the below command for generating the AAR file:

`./android.sh -d --enable-android-media-codec --enable-android-zlib --enable-lame --enable-shine --enable-opus --enable-libvorbis --disable-arm-v7a-neon --disable-x86 --disable-x86-64 --disable-arm-v7a`

When I import the AAR file to my project I get this error in the runtime:

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.arthenica.smartexception.java.Exceptions" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~jEhW86BHvWX75oI4OlJ1Ew==/com.pkappstudio.mediatools-jxJu72Vroc6h16UeNwn0Mw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~jEhW86BHvWX75oI4OlJ1Ew==/com.pkappstudio.mediatools-jxJu72Vroc6h16UeNwn0Mw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~jEhW86BHvWX75oI4OlJ1Ew==/com.pkappstudio.mediatools-jxJu72Vroc6h16UeNwn0Mw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]`

Now, could anyone please help me to solve the issue, and tell me the correct way to genrate AAR file for only video to auto conversion and ffprobe. My ultimate goal is to minimize the app size.

Comment: The repo "ffmpeg-kit" seems to depend on this repo: https://github.com/tanersener/smart-exception . You need to reference that repo.

Comment: @zomega yes, I know that. I also tried to add `implementation 'com.arthenica:smart-exception-java9:0.2.1'` as a dependency. But, the issue still remains.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the issue by adding `smart-exception-common-0.2.1.jar` and `smart-exception-java-0.2.1.jar` from https://github.com/tanersener/smart-exception/releases